# Offline application with WEB_SQL

Tags: angularjs, web-sql

I am working on offline application with WEB-SQL and angularJS

I am facing lot of issue that I am unable to resolve with proper solution
When Application start how do I know that I need to create database because application starting first time or browser has been reset.
 to solve this what I am doing

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Services')
.service('LocalDb', function($q){
var db = openDatabase('LocalDb', '1.0', 'Local database', 100 * 1024 * 1024);
return {
    getData : function(condition){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        if(condition == null)
            var query = "select * from TABLENAME";
        else
            var query = "select * from TABLENAME where COLUMNNAME ='" + condition + "'";
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(query, [], success, failure);
        });
        function success(tx, results){
            defer.resolve(results.rows.item(0));
        };
        function failure(tx, err){
            defer.reject(err.message);
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my controller that runs when application bootstrap where I am fetching data if data not found then I am calling API to load data from server :
I know I am not handling database properly because I am unable to find the best practice of managing web-sql API This is my first offline project.

```
try{
    var Template = LocalDb.getData('a71391ea11e5f4e2bb1ec0cecdec5c69').then(function(response){
        if(response){
            scope.baseObject = JSON.parse(response.baseTemplateObject);
        }
        else{
            callApi = true;
        }
    });    
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    callApi = true;
}
if(callApi) {
    /*calling api and creating data base then creating table and then inserting response data into table */ 
}
```

Problem is when application start there is no table so .then function in controller will not even execute.

Also I am not able find how to handle callbacks like

- table not found error
- data not found error
- database not found error
- also asynchronous call of websql also creating some problem.

Can anyone please help me with some best practice of doing this.

Any help would be a great support.
Thanks in advance.